# How to add client-side unobtrusive validation on property of every item in List and print the message once?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, unobtrusive-validation

I have a view model:

```
public class RatingsEditViewModel
{
    [PropertyOnEveryItemInListRequired(Common.TranslationsEnums.DetailObjectRating.ValidationMessageRateEveryParameter, "Rating")]
    public List<ReviewCategoryViewModel> CategoryTypes { get; set; }
        = new List<ReviewCategoryViewModel>();
}
```

The ReviewCategoryViewModel:

```
public class ReviewCategoryViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Rating { get; set; }
}
```

I've created a custom attribute and adapter to validate server side, like this:

```
    public class PropertyOnEveryItemInListRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
    {
        private string errorMessage;
        private string propertyName;

        public PropertyOnEveryItemInListRequiredAttribute(int id, string propertyName)
        {
            this.errorMessage = Translations.Translator.GetTranslation(id);
            this.propertyName = propertyName;
        }

        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            ModelClientValidationRule propertyOnEveryItemInListRequiredAttribute = new ModelClientValidationRule();
            propertyOnEveryItemInListRequiredAttribute.ErrorMessage = this.errorMessage;
            propertyOnEveryItemInListRequiredAttribute.ValidationType = "propertyoneveryiteminlistrequiredattribute";

            yield return propertyOnEveryItemInListRequiredAttribute;
        }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            var list = value as IList;

            if (list != null)
            {
                foreach (var element in list)
                {
                    var property = element.GetType().GetProperty(this.propertyName);

                    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(int))
                    {
                        var intValue = (int)property.GetValue(element, null);

                        if (intValue == 0)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                }

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            return this.IsValid(value) ? ValidationResult.Success : new ValidationResult(this.errorMessage);
        }
    }


    public class PropertyOnEveryItemInListRequiredAttributeAdapter : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<PropertyOnEveryItemInListRequiredAttribute>
    {
        public PropertyOnEveryItemInListRequiredAttributeAdapter(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, PropertyOnEveryItemInListRequiredAttribute attribute)
        : base(metadata, context, attribute)
        {
        }

        public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
        {
            return this.Attribute.GetClientValidationRules(this.Metadata, this.ControllerContext);
        }
    }
```

added the adapter in global.asax.

The server-side validation works and correctly displays my error message.

And in the view:

```
<div class="row evaluation-content modal-rating">
    @{
        for (var i = 0; i < Model.CategoryTypes.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="col-xs-12 evaluation-row">

                @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.CategoryTypes[@i].Id)
                @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.CategoryTypes[@i].Name)

                <span class="name">@Model.CategoryTypes[i].Name: *</span>
                <div class="rating-control pull-right">

                    @{
                        for (var j = 10; j > 0; j--)
                        {
                            <span id="@j"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
                        }
                    }

                </div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.CategoryTypes[@i].Rating, new { @id = "rating-" + i.ToString(), @style = "visibility: hidden; width: 0; height: 0; margin: 0;" })
                @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.CategoryTypes[i].Rating)*@

            </div>
        }
    }

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryTypes)
</div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitButton" />
```

And added a js filling of the inputted number of stars:

```
$("#submitButton").on("click", function () {
    var evalContainer = $(".row .evaluation-content div.rating-control");

    for (var i = 0, div; div = evalContainer[i]; i++) {
        for (var j = 0, span; span = div.children[j]; j++) {
            if (span.className === "active") {
                $("#rating-" + i).val(span.id);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I know this is probably not the best solution (looks bad) so please feel free to comment it too.

I've added the method to validator in js (it's a dummy):

```
$.validator.addMethod("propertyoneveryiteminlistrequiredattribute", function (value, element, params) {
    if (!isValueZero(value))
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("propertyoneveryiteminlistrequiredattribute", ["propertyoneveryiteminlistrequiredattribute"], function (options) {
    options.rules["propertyoneveryiteminlistrequiredattribute"] = true;
    options.messages["propertyoneveryiteminlistrequiredattribute"] = options.message;
});

function isValueZero(str) {
    return parseInt(str) == 0;
}
```

I need to validate the input of the user on all the categories (he needs to pick a star (value of rating on each element), but if he fails to do so, I need to only write the validation message once for the whole list, appended after the controls of all categories.

The GetClientValidationRules is not fired, the data-val attributes are not populated, also the addMethod to adapters is not called. Is there a way to handle this in unobtrusive validation? If not, what would be the best way to handle client-side validation of this list?

Comment: You apply your validation attribute to a complex property (`CategoryTypes`) but you view does not generate a form control for `CategoryTypes` (and nor should it) so you cannot get client side validation.

Comment: Why are you not just using a `[Required]` attribute on `int? Rating` (nullable property)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I need to only view the validation message once for whole list (if one is not filled) appended to the list. And I'd like to use the custom attribute I've made for backend. What would you advise me to handle this situation with plz?

Comment: You cannot tap into the client side jquery validate library with this. You can always just create your own script that is fired in the forms .submit()` event that checks if any of the values are invalid, and if so display your a message in the DOM (and remove it on the `.keyup()` event of the inputs for `Rating`)